# Read values from properties file in spring with no key

Tags: java, spring, hadoop, hdfs

I have the following in my `beans.xml`

```
<hdp:hbase-configuration configuration-ref="hadoopConfiguration"
    zk-quorum="${hbase.zk.host}" zk-port="${hbase.zk.port}" />
```

where I can read `hbase.zk.host` from `system.properties` as it has the key `zk-quorun` but I need to place a value with no key like below

```
<hdp:configuration id="hadoopConfiguration">
    fs.defaultFS=hdfs://hadoop:54310
</hdp:configuration>
```

I need to read `fs.defaultFS=hdfs://hadoop:54310` from properties file

so I placed it as

```
#Hadoop URL
haddop.url=fs.defaultFS=hdfs://hadoop:54310
```

in `system.properties` and made changes in `beans.xml` as

```
<hdp:configuration id="hadoopConfiguration">
    "${hadoop.url}"
</hdp:configuration>
```

I'm unable to read it, can any one tell me how to read when there is no key ??

Comment: not sure but there seem to be a syntax error : hadoop.url vs haddop.url

Answer (score 1):

You should add those config in your beans.xml. Note: "location = your source folder"

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />   
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations" value="classpath:/config/*.properties" />
</bean>
```

Comment: I added it, there is no problem with that, I'm asking how to add `"${hadoop.url}"` without any key. Please take a detailed look at my question

Comment: my `beans.xml` contains those already. That is not the problem

Comment: not sure but there seem to be a syntax error : hadoop.url vs haddop.url

Comment: I think your url error *fs.defaultFS=hdfs://hadoop:54310*
Please try haddop.url= "fs.defaultFS=hdfs://hadoop:54310"

Answer (score -1):

Solved it,

my `beans.xml` was unable to read the complete line from `system.properties` so I added only the part which is variable in `system.properties` like below

```
<hdp:configuration id="hadoopConfiguration">
    fs.defaultFS=hdfs://"${hadoop.url}":54310
</hdp:configuration>
```

and in `system.properties` file

```
#Hadoop URL
hadoop.url=hadoop
```

no other changes its working now !!